# Event(Start,Finish),Max event on 1 day. Perfomance issue in c++

Tags: c++, optimization

They give me N sets of start/finish time EX:(8:45/12:00).
After return MAX number of events one man can partecipate without overlapping.
(one event finish at 8:00 and one starting at 8:00 are not overlapping).

I've made a basic class with start & finish for every event.
After that, I made a recursive function to make "event chain".
My Solution do its job with N < 100 but because is O(n!) [i think] with N>100  my (very) old computer doesn't give me the aswer fast enough.

```cpp
class Event{
public:
int hh,mm;
int ehh,emm;
};

int chain(Event* array,int nchain,int index,int N){
int max = nchain;
for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
    if(overlapping(app[index],app[i])){
        int tempmax = chain(array,nchain+1,i,N);
        if(tempmax > max){
            max = tempmax;
        }
    }
}
return max;
}

bool overlapping(Event a,Event b){
    if(a.ehh<b.hh || (a.ehh==b.hh && a.emm<=b.mm) ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive solution may be O(2<sup>N</sup>) but:

1. You appear to have logic for pruning when a subset has an internal scheduling conflict, which has already helped the complexity greatly.
2. You can do much better with dynamic programming.  This problem sounds like it has very nice domination characteristics -- if one set of N events leaves you free at time X, and another set gives you N+1 events and free at or earlier than time X, the former doesn't need to be considered any further.

   Prune dominated subsets and continue exploring the optimal frontier.

Another perspective (that leads to the same algorithm) is to consider that, of all schedules which include a certain event Y, the choice of what to do before Y starts and the choice of what to do after Y ends are completely independent, and can be separately optimized.

I believe, but offer no proof, that your final algorithm will be O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

There's a better approach to this problem using a greedy solution. First we need to sort the events by finish time in ascending order. This way, it's always optimal to choose the next event in the array which doesn't overlap with the set of chosen events. The time complexity will be O(nlogn).

```
#include<algorithm>
class Event{
    public:
    int hh,mm;
    int ehh,emm;
};

bool overlapping(Event a, Event b){//assumes a,b sorted by finish time
    return b.hh < a.ehh || (b.hh == a.ehh && b.mm < a.emm);
}

int eventScheduler(Event* Array, int N){
    if(N==0)return 0;
    std::sort(Array,Array+N,[](Event a,Event b){
        return a.ehh < b.ehh || (a.ehh == b.ehh && a.emm < b.emm);
    });

    int result=1;
    Event lastChosen= Array[0];
    for(int i=1;i < N;i++){
        if(!overlapping(lastChosen,Array[i])){
            result++;
            lastChosen=Array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

An intuition of why this works: If we chose the first event of the array, all the events that became impossible to choose contain the finish time of the first event, so there's no way to choose more than one event from this subset. Choosing the first event minimizes the finish time, allowing to schedule more events. After discarding those events we are in the same state where we started.